# Bash functions to shorten some commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using django and I wanted to shorten some of the commands like python manage.py xxx or tar -xzvf . etc

I tried

```
mng(){
  python manage.py $("$@")
}
```

it didn't work

```
$("python manage.py $@")
```

didn't work as well

what am I messing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use aliases for this:

```
alias mng='python manage.py'
```

You can put persistent alias definitions in `~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: note that aliases are available in interactive shells only.

Comment: @A.Zaben Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer if this is the solution you decided to use. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have some parentheses you don't need.  Try this:

```
mng() {
  python manage.py "$@"
}
```

You do want the quotes, or extra arguments will be split on spaces.